# How to generate scale-independent random floating point numbers?

Tags: python, random, floating-point, distribution

I want to generate what I'm choosing to call "arbitrary" positive floating-point numbers; that is, random numbers which are independent of scale (in other words, numbers whose logarithms are uniformly distributed). I'm not much of a mathematician, so for all I know there may be another name for what I'm after.

Here's my initial, naïve solution:

```python
import sys
import random

def arbitrary(min=sys.float_info.min_10_exp, max=sys.float_info.max_10_exp):
    return 10 ** random.uniform(min, max)
```

It strikes me that this is probably not ideal: for one thing, I imagine that there might be some interaction between the limited precision of `random.uniform()` and the floating point representation itself that would cause bunching and gaps in the expected output at higher orders of magnitude.

Is there a better approach? <s>Would it make more sense to just produce a string of random bits and then turn that into the floating point number they represent?</s>

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Oli Charlesworth in the comments, the "convert random bits to a float" idea doesn't do what I want (which is a uniform distribution of log(n)).

Comment: The latter approach will not work; the PDF will be piecewise flat, with a step at each power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your approach doesn't return some numbers. For example, there is no floating-point number between `1.0` and `1.0000000000000002`, but `10**1.0000000000000002` is `10.000000000000005`, and there are two numbers between `10.0` and `10.000000000000005`: `10.000000000000002` and `10.000000000000004`. Those two numbers will never be returned by your algorithm.

But you can cheat and use `Decimal` to exponentiate with greater precision:

```
>>> float(10 ** Decimal('1'))
10.0
>>> float(10 ** Decimal('1.0000000000000001'))
10.000000000000002
>>> float(10 ** Decimal('1.00000000000000015'))
10.000000000000004
>>> float(10 ** Decimal('1.0000000000000002'))
10.000000000000005
```

So, `arbitrary` needs to generate random `Decimal` exponents of sufficient precision and use them as exponents. Assuming 64 binary digits is enough precision for the exponent, the code would look like this:

```
import sys, random
from decimal import Decimal

def _random_decimal(minval, maxval, added_prec):
    # generate a Decimal in the range [minval, maxval) with the
    # precision of additional ADDED_PREC binary digits
    rangelen = maxval - minval
    denom = rangelen << added_prec
    return minval + Decimal(rangelen) * random.randrange(denom) / denom

def arbitrary():
    min_exp = sys.float_info.min_exp - sys.float_info.mant_dig
    max_exp = sys.float_info.max_exp
    return float(2 ** _random_decimal(min_exp, max_exp, 64))
```

Comment: Using `Decimal` to overcome the precision limit is a neat trick, and of course it would be simple to extend this approach to use negative exponents as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I've extended it for negative exponents a minute ago, please reload. :)